# Is there a way to 'merge' two columns, where the values of new column are the name of the original column that had a specific value, group wise?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

I have a dataframe (will call it 'df') with a decent amount of variables (numeric, logical and characters) representing an experiment where different cell types were moved from a specific medium, to another one, and the activity of the cell was quantified at specific times. The first and second columns hold the name of the 'source' medium, and the name of the medium the cells were moved to, respectively; the third column describes the time at which the activity was quantified, the fourth is the cell type, the fifth is the activity measured, and this is where it gets funny.

I have two main questions, the first one is to know if there is an 'R-esque' way to did what I did to obtain the sixth column, which contains the increase/decrease (in percentage) of the value in 'Activity' relative from that present in the previous row, but in a group manner (each group consist of a combination of Cell.Type, Pre.Medium and Time), so that's why its value is NA everytime the value of Time is zero.

Assuming this is my dataframe (I've simplified it in order to make my question more clear):

```
df <- structure(list(Pre.Medium = c("Medium1", "Medium1", "Medium1", 
"Medium2", "Medium2", "Medium2", "Medium1", "Medium1", "Medium1", 
"Medium2", "Medium2", "Medium2"), Pos.Medium = c("Medium2", "Medium2", 
"Medium2", "Medium1", "Medium1", "Medium1", "Medium2", "Medium2", 
"Medium2", "Medium1", "Medium1", "Medium1"), Time = c(0, 2, 4, 
0, 2, 4, 0, 2, 4, 0, 2, 4), Cell.Type = c("Cell_A", "Cell_A", 
"Cell_A", "Cell_A", "Cell_A", "Cell_A", "Cell_B", "Cell_B", "Cell_B", 
"Cell_B", "Cell_B", "Cell_B"), Activity = c(0.5, 1, 2, 2, 1, 
0.5, 0.2, 0.8, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4), Percent.Increase = c(NA, 
100, 100, NA, -50, -50, NA, 300, -75, NA, 0, 100), Primary.Increase = c(NA, 
TRUE, FALSE, NA, TRUE, FALSE, NA, TRUE, FALSE, NA, FALSE, FALSE
), Secondary.Increase = c(NA, FALSE, FALSE, NA, FALSE, FALSE, 
NA, FALSE, FALSE, NA, FALSE, TRUE)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), problems = structure(list(
    row = 1L, col = NA_character_, expected = "8 columns", actual = "9 columns", 
    file = "'new 2'"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), spec = structure(list(cols = list(Pre.Medium = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Pos.Medium = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Time = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Cell.Type = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Activity = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Percent.Increase = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Primary.Increase = structure(list(), class = c("collector_logical", 
"collector")), Secondary.Increase = structure(list(), class = c("collector_logical", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

```
### Pre.Med Pos.Med Time  Cell.Type Activity  Percent.Increase  Primary.Increase Secondary.Increase
### Medium1 Medium2   0    Cell_A    0.5           NA           NA                NA 
### Medium1 Medium2   2    Cell_A    1             100          TRUE              FALSE
### Medium1 Medium2   4    Cell_A    2             100          FALSE             FALSE
### Medium2 Medium1   0    Cell_A    2             NA           NA                NA
### Medium2 Medium1   2    Cell_A    1            -50           TRUE              FALSE
### Medium2 Medium1   4    Cell_A    0.5          -50           FALSE             FALSE
### Medium1 Medium2   0    Cell_B    0.2           NA           NA                NA
### Medium1 Medium2   2    Cell_B    0.8           300          TRUE              FALSE
### Medium1 Medium2   4    Cell_B    0.2          -75           FALSE             FALSE
### Medium2 Medium1   0    Cell_B    0.2           NA           NA                NA
### Medium2 Medium1   2    Cell_B    0.2           0            FALSE             FALSE
### Medium2 Medium1   4    Cell_B    0.4           100          FALSE             TRUE
```

I did by using the group_by and mutate functions, and then the lag function to calculate the increase/decrease from the previous and the previous previous row, was there a better way to do so? For my specific case, lag was enough, but what if I had more than three time measurements in each 'group' and needed to go way behind to calculate it? With my approach, at some point I would've had to use something like lag(lag(lag(lag(lag((Activity / lag(Activity)) - 1) * 100)))) etc.

The other thing is something I have not been able to figure out in any way, and it is to turn my 'wide' dataset into a long one, by turning my columns 'Primary.Increase' and 'Secondary.Increase' into a column named 'Increase.Type' where its value will consist, for each group (combination of Cell.Type, Pre.Med and Time), in the name of the column (either Primary.Response or Secondary.Response) where the value of one of its member was TRUE. It should look something like this:

```
df <- structure(list(Pre.Med = c("Medium1", "Medium1", "Medium1", "Medium2", 
"Medium2", "Medium2", "Medium1", "Medium1", "Medium1", "Medium2", 
"Medium2", "Medium2"), Pos.Med = c("Medium2", "Medium2", "Medium2", 
"Medium1", "Medium1", "Medium1", "Medium2", "Medium2", "Medium2", 
"Medium1", "Medium1", "Medium1"), Time = c(0, 2, 4, 0, 2, 4, 
0, 2, 4, 0, 2, 4), Cell.Type = c("Cell_A", "Cell_A", "Cell_A", 
"Cell_A", "Cell_A", "Cell_A", "Cell_B", "Cell_B", "Cell_B", "Cell_B", 
"Cell_B", "Cell_B"), Activity = c(0.5, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0.5, 0.2, 
0.8, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4), Percent.Inc = c(NA, 100, 100, NA, -50, 
-50, NA, 300, -75, NA, 0, 100), Increase.Type = c("Primary.Increase", 
"Primary.Increase", "Primary.Increase", "Primary.Increase", "Primary.Increase", 
"Primary.Increase", "Primary.Increase", "Primary.Increase", "Primary.Increase", 
"Secondary.Increase", "Secondary.Increase", "Secondary.Increase"
)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(Pre.Med = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Pos.Med = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Time = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Cell.Type = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Activity = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Percent.Inc = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Increase.Type = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

```
### Pre.Med Pos.Med Time  Cell.Type Activity    Percent.Inc Increase.Type 
### Medium1 Medium2   0    Cell_A    0.5           NA         Primary.Increase
### Medium1 Medium2   2    Cell_A    1             100        Primary.Increase
### Medium1 Medium2   4    Cell_A    2             100        Primary.Increase
### Medium2 Medium1   0    Cell_A    2             NA         Primary.Increase
### Medium2 Medium1   2    Cell_A    1            -50         Primary.Increase
### Medium2 Medium1   4    Cell_A    0.5          -50         Primary.Increase
### Medium1 Medium2   0    Cell_B    0.2           NA         Primary.Increase
### Medium1 Medium2   2    Cell_B    0.8           300        Primary.Increase
### Medium1 Medium2   4    Cell_B    0.2          -75         Primary.Increase
### Medium2 Medium1   0    Cell_B    0.2           NA         Secondary.Increase
### Medium2 Medium1   2    Cell_B    0.2           0          Secondary.Increase     
### Medium2 Medium1   4    Cell_B    0.4           100        Secondary.Increase
```

Is there a way to do this in the first place? I'd assume so, but so far I've not been able to do it :/ 
I'm an undergraduate in biology relatively new to R, I'm loving what you can do with it but I'm still a long way from being good at it.

Any help is heavily appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the first question.
If you do something like:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Cell.Type, Pre.Medium, Pos.Medium) %>%
  arrange(Time, .by_group = TRUE) %>% # remove if Time is always ascending
  mutate(Percent.Increase = ((Activity / lag(Activity)) - 1) * 100)
```

the calculation of `Percent.Increase` is vectorized,
so it won't matter how long `Activity` is
(see also my last explanation below).

For the second question,
if I understand correctly,
you can do it like this:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Cell.Type, Pre.Medium, Pos.Medium) %>%
  mutate(Increase.Type = if (any(Secondary.Increase, na.rm = TRUE)) "Secondary.Increase" else "Primary.Increase") %>%
  select(-(Primary.Increase:Secondary.Increase))
# A tibble: 12 x 7
# Groups:   Cell.Type, Pre.Medium, Pos.Medium [4]
   Pre.Medium Pos.Medium  Time Cell.Type Activity Percent.Increase Increase.Type     
   <chr>      <chr>      <dbl> <chr>        <dbl>            <dbl> <chr>             
 1 Medium1    Medium2        0 Cell_A         0.5               NA Primary.Increase  
 2 Medium1    Medium2        2 Cell_A         1                100 Primary.Increase  
 3 Medium1    Medium2        4 Cell_A         2                100 Primary.Increase  
 4 Medium2    Medium1        0 Cell_A         2                 NA Primary.Increase  
 5 Medium2    Medium1        2 Cell_A         1                -50 Primary.Increase  
 6 Medium2    Medium1        4 Cell_A         0.5              -50 Primary.Increase  
 7 Medium1    Medium2        0 Cell_B         0.2               NA Primary.Increase  
 8 Medium1    Medium2        2 Cell_B         0.8              300 Primary.Increase  
 9 Medium1    Medium2        4 Cell_B         0.2              -75 Primary.Increase  
10 Medium2    Medium1        0 Cell_B         0.2               NA Secondary.Increase
11 Medium2    Medium1        2 Cell_B         0.2                0 Secondary.Increase
12 Medium2    Medium1        4 Cell_B         0.4              100 Secondary.Increase
```

The transformation inside `mutate` sees *all* values from the group,
so `any(Secondary.Increase, na.rm = TRUE)` receives all elements at once,
and if we only return 1 value,
it'll be copied to fit the group size.